# How can I set up a self-contained Linqpad project which talks to a service that requires my namespaces to match up with those of the service?

Tags: c#, wcf, linqpad

I am attempting to test some some basic WCF service code via LinqPad.  When I attach to the service process, all of the serialized parameters are set to null.  I believe the problem is that it is unable to serialization due to the classes being in the wrong namespace.  However, I am unable to figure out how to place them in the correct namespace without having them be compiled outside of Linqpad.  This works, but prevents the LinqPad project from being as self-contained.

Things I've tried:

1. Creating a self-contained visual studio project.  This worked once I moved everything into a namespace matching that of my existing code.  However, I wish to run the test code in LinqPad.
2. Have my Linqpad project reference a dll containing the service class.  This works, but makes the lingpad project less self-contained.
3. `ContractNamespaceAttribute.ClrNamespace` looks like it might resolve the problem, but it can only be applied to assemblies and modules.

Is there a way to get this working in Linqpad as a self-contained project (e.g., by somehow telling LinqPad to put my classes in a specific namespace)?

Comment: This will get the generated classes out of the LinqPad.User namespace: `#define NONEST`. Unfortunately I don't know how to get them into a specific namespace.

Comment: I suspect he monitors the linqpad tag, but I emailed Joseph Albahari a link to this.